# How to select multiple alias columns from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried multiple different solutions and I'm still not getting the results I want from my `SQL Server` query. I have two tables, `PRIMARY_CATEGORY` which has a `Category_Id` as the **PK** and an associated `Category_Name` for each. There are 4 different categories. The other table is `PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY` which has a `Subcategory_Id`**(PK)**, `Subcategory_Name`, and the `Category_Id` as a **FK** to the `PRIMARY_CATEGORY` table.

I have a select statement right now which is returning back the entire list from the `Subcategory_Name` in one big column, but I want it to separate these into 4 different columns for each of the Category_Names. So it should be something like (With ~ showing the omitted values 7-49)

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
Value A1 | Value B1 | Value C1 | Value D1
Value A2 | Value B2 | Value C2 | Value D2
Value A3 | Value B3 | Value C3 | Value D3
Value A4 | Value B4 | Value C4 | Value D4
Value A5 | Value B5 | Value C5 | Value D5
Value A6 | Value B6 | Value C6 | Value D6
   ~     |    ~     |     ~    |    ~ 
Value A50| Value B50| Value C50| Value D50
```

Here's what I have, but I'm getting no results when I run this. It formats the columns the way I want though.

```
SELECT 
    psc1.Subcategory_Name as 'Column 1',
    psc2.Subcategory_Name as 'Column 2',
    psc3.Subcategory_Name as 'Column 3',
    psc4.Subcategory_Name as 'Column 4'
FROM PRIMARY_CATEGORY pc
INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY psc1 ON psc1.Category_Id = pc.Category_Id
INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY psc2 ON psc2.Category_Id = pc.Category_Id
INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY psc3 ON psc3.Category_Id = pc.Category_Id
INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY psc4 ON psc4.Category_Id = pc.Category_Id    
WHERE 
    psc1.Category_Id IN (select Category_Id from PRIMARY_CATEGORY where Category_Name = 'Category 1')
    psc2.Category_Id IN (select Category_Id from PRIMARY_CATEGORY where Category_Name = 'Category 2')
    psc3.Category_Id IN (select Category_Id from PRIMARY_CATEGORY where Category_Name = 'Category 3')
    psc4.Category_Id IN (select Category_Id from PRIMARY_CATEGORY where Category_Name = 'Category 4')
```

Do I need this many inner joins to do this or can this be done with just one? Each column should basically only show the Subcategory_Names that are associated with the Category.

I feel like this is perhaps an overly complicated query to accomplish this task but I'm not sure of a better way to do this.

Running what radar has suggested with the MAX values but without the group by, I'm getting something like this

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
Value A50 | Value A50 | Value C50 | Value D50
```

When I run that with the `Subcategory_Id` I get this

```
Category_Id  | Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  | Column 4
           1 | [Blank]   | [Blank]   | Value C50 | [Blank]
           2 | [Blank]   | Value A50 | [Blank]   | [Blank]
           3 | [Blank]   | [Blank]   | [Blank]   | Value D50
           4 | Value A50 | [Blank]   | [Blank]   | [Blank]
```

Comment: Have a look at [pivoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

you can get it using `case based aggregation`

you can also get the same result using `pivot`

```
SELECT pc.category_id, 
       MAX(case when 
                pc.Category_Name ='Category 1'
                then psc.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as 'Column 1',
       MAX(case when 
                pc.Category_Name ='Category 2'
                then psc.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as 'Column 2',
       MAX(case when 
                pc.Category_Name ='Category 3'
                then psc.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as 'Column 3',
       MAX(case when 
                pc.Category_Name ='Category 4'
                then psc.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as 'Column 4',
FROM PRIMARY_CATEGORY pc
INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY psc ON pc.category_id = psc.category_id
GROUP BY pc.category_id
```

Comment: I have used this query, but removed MAX and GROUP BY as I want to return all the values for each category though now I have a new problem. How can I remove all the NULL values from the results after doing this? If I try wrapping the whole thing in a `SELECT * FROM () AS Results` and then doing `WHERE IS NOT NULL` but that only works for one column at a time. How can I return all the fields with no NULL or blank values?

Comment: @Shintsu, we are converting rows to columns using MAX, it would recturn all categories, adding category id also to the select, see the edit.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what I'm getting when I run the original query you posted and this updated one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required result set with a pivot operator as follows:

```
SELECT pivotedCataegories.[Category 1]
       , pivotedCataegories.[Category 2]
       , pivotedCataegories.[Category 3]
       , pivotedCataegories.[Category 4]
FROM (
    SELECT pc.Category_Name
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.Category_Id ORDER BY psc.Subcategory_Id) AS subCatNumber
        , psc.Subcategory_Name
    FROM PRIMARY_CATEGORY pc
    INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY  psc ON psc.Category_Id  = pc.Category_Id 
) AS categories
PIVOT (
    MAX(s.Subcategory_Name) 
    FOR s.Category_Name IN ([Category 1], [Category 2], [Category 3], [Category 4])
) pivotedCataegories
```

The PIVOT operator creates a result set with one column for each value specified by `s.Category_Name IN ([Categoasry 1], [Category 2], [Category 3], [Category 4])` and one row for unique value of `s.subCatNumber`. The value of each category column is `MAX(s.Subcategory_Name) WHERE s.Category_Name = 'Category X' GROUP BY s.subCatNumber`

This query is equivalent to

```
SELECT MAX(case when 
                categories.Category_Name = 'Category 1'
                then categories.catDesc 
                else NULL end) as 'Category 1',
       MAX(case when 
                categories.Category_Name = 'Category 2'
                then categories.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as [Category 2],
       MAX(case when 
                categories.Category_Name = 'Category 3'
                then categories.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as [Category 3],
       MAX(case when 
                categories.Category_Name = 'Category 4'
                then categories.Subcategory_Name 
                else NULL end) as [Category 4]
FROM (
     SELECT pc.Category_Name
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.Category_Id ORDER BY psc.Subcategory_Id) AS subCatNumber
            , psc.Subcategory_Name
    FROM PRIMARY_CATEGORY pc
    INNER JOIN PRIMARY_SUBCATEGORY  psc ON psc.Category_Id  = pc.Category_Id 
) categories
GROUP BY subCatNumber
```